# Is @keyframe iteration broken in stylus? Getting error using the example from docs

Tags: stylus

[image]

[This is the example straight out of the docs](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/keyframes.html)

Slightly changed, Different error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It was a bug. Fixed in 0.44.0.](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/issues/1443)